# CSS - All elements in parent match last-child selector. How can I add styling to all the elements contained in a form but the last one?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a bottom border to all but the last direct children of a form by using the following styling block:

But all the children of the form seem to match the `:last-child` selector.

Here is my code:

```css
 .form-for:not(:last-child) > div {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #6d6e71;
    }
```

```html
<form class="form-for">
        <div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-for-label">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="Name" value="" placeholder="Name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-for-label">Description</label>
                <input type="text" name="Description" value="" placeholder="Description">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-for-label">Creation Date</label>
                <input type="text" name="Creation Date" value="" placeholder="Creation Date">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

It might be important to mention that this form is dynamically generated using the [react-form-for-object library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-form-for-object).

Comment: it sould be like that `.form-for > div:not(:last-child)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to select direct children you can use `parent > child`:

```css
.form-for>div:not(:last-of-type)>div {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #6d6e71;
}
```

```html
<form class="form-for">
  <div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="form-for-label">Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="Name" value="" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="form-for-label">Description</label>
      <input type="text" name="Description" value="" placeholder="Description">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="form-for-label">Creation Date</label>
      <input type="text" name="Creation Date" value="" placeholder="Creation Date">
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: but not between the form and the outer `div`s

Comment: I've run the code snippet that you provided by itself and it seems to work fine. However, when I replace the css block I wrote with yours, it seems act differently by adding a bottom border to all of the divs with the class "form-group".

Comment: Could you check if the html structure still matches? (`<FORM>` `<DIV>` `<DIV>`)?

Comment: The HTML structure still matches that pattern. As you can see in [this image](https://ibb.co/dgxRen), adding the block that you provided did not work as expected; it adds a bottom border to all of the divs contained by another div inside the form.

Comment: Your `<form>` contains elements after the divs so they aren't last childs. I editet the answer to only select div, which are not last childs using `:last-of-type`

Answer (score 0):

try this :)

```
.form-for > div:not(:last-child) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #6d6e71;
}
```

another solution (optional)

```
.form-for > div {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #6d6e71;
}
.form-for > div:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0px solid #fff;
}
```

Comment: I've tried that, but it doesn't seem to work either as it adds a bottom border to all the direct children of .form-for.

Comment: I tested this and  It is working fine I am going to update my answer with another solution for this.